# What would've happened to Mars if our Moon crashed into it?

Tags: space, aliens, moons, planets

Would scientists on the other side of blast survive in a bunker?
I got an alien using telekinesis abilities to move Moon with the speed of " 1 hour till collide from the moment Moon left the orbit". So how devastating the effect will be?

Comment: I read some time ago that the impact between Theia and a Mars-sized planet, from which the Earth and the Moon arised, had a relative velocity between both bodies of around four kilometers per second. That's pretty close to Mach 3 in our atmosphere. That's orders of magnitude slower than the figures in Michael's answer and it still obliterared two planets completely, due to the sheer amount of mass invoved. Maybe you'd like to crash Phobos or Deimos on Mars instead?

Comment: Read this: https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/

Answer (score 3):

[Mars is a long distance away](http://www.distancetomars.com/).

Also Mars is only twice the diameter of the Moon, and the moon is 1/9 the mass of Mars.

To move from Earth orbit to Mars in 1 hour, you need an average speed at least 73 million kilometers per hour, which is about 7% of the speed of light.

Calculating the pure kinetic energy of the Moon as it smacks into Mars, it comes down to approximately 30 x 10<sup>36</sup> Joule (not counting relativistic effects). The Sun outputs 3.6 x 10<sup>26</sup> Joule each second. So in that moment of collision, let us say it takes 1 second... this Moon-Mars system outputs the energy of **100 billion Suns**.

Since the Earth is approximately the same distance from the Sun as from Mars — even a little bit closer — this means that when the shockwave of energy from this collision reaches Earth... the side of Earth that is facing Mars is instantly roasted to crisps.

Would you at this point chance that someone on a bunker on Mars, at the very epicenter of this 100 billion suns release of energy, will have any chance to survive; in a place where the surface of the Sun is — in comparison — freezing cold?

Short answer: No, not a chance... they will be blasted into elementary particles.

How devastating will the effects be? You obliterate the Moon and Mars into elementary particles... you vaporize half the surface of the Earth in the process... you make ripples on the surfaces of the Sun, Jupiter and Saturn.

Comment: Well hopefully aliens already snatched the planet Earth to another galaxy. :)

Comment: Will the blast reach the moon of Jupiter- Calisto? Thanks for swift answer.

Comment: @UnduLationer Yes of course it will. I say again: **100 billion Suns** concentrated on a (relatively speaking) very tiny area.

Comment: @UnduLationer And here is the fun part of course: how did these "telepathic abilities" impart energy of the equivalent amount of 3 000 **years** worth of output from our Sun on the Moon? Where were these aliens storing that energy? Using E = MC^2 (the mass-energy equivalence) that amount of energy is 300 million billion tons of mass. That is one huge telepathic alien...

Comment: Ok, how many days it's acceptable for Moon to travel and smack the Mars, so the blast won't affect Calisto? That alien is just extremely powerful, its tool for such power is telekinesis, not telepathic. My bad. I got a scientific base there, I don't want it to be destroyed...

Comment: @UnduLationer If you want **science** in the equation, then the problem is still that of **energy**. To move the Moon you need to impart ridiculous amounts of **energy** onto it. Where are you getting that energy from? You say "Telekinesis". That is not science; that is **magic**. And with magic in the story you can just assume that your alien grabs the Moon... rushes it over to Mars... and then uses this same magic to slow down the Moon before smacking it fairly "gently" into Mars. Since you have ventured into using magic already, then you use the same magic to shape the story as you wish.